# Why there is no reveal token when i making discord bot?

Tags: discord

Im just a new in discord bot and i want to learn how to create ones. Every youtube and google tutorial, there is a button to reveal and copy the token but there is no reveal and copy discord bot token in my discord. Anyone know how to solve this?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

As of very recently (this is not documented in their changelog so I cannot provide an exact date), you can only view your token when creating your bot for the first time.

If you have lost or forgotten your token, you can go to:

[https://discord.com/developers/applications/{your_application_ID}/bot](https://discord.com/developers/applications/%7Byour_application_ID%7D/bot)

There, you would have to regenerate a token by clicking "Reset token" (see image below), which will stop the old one from working and provide you with a new one. Once again, this new one will only visible the first time you reset it.

[image]

Note: users with 2FA will have to authenticate with their chosen authenticator.

Comment: its my firsttime, when i create my bot, i cant see the link

Answer (score 1):

Try another browser.

I had the same issue (token not showing no matter how many times I clicked on that reset button) on firefox. I tried with another browser (I happened to have a windows with edge on hand) and the token showed up when I reset it.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried accessing the bot using the https://discord.com/developers/applications page.

Also, in the Discord client (app), these is an option in Advanced that you can turn on [Developer Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7rHn.png).

I hope this help solving your problem!

Comment: thank you for answering. but isnt work. but i solve it by resetting the token and using the 6 digit verification.